# Non-integrable function that has an antiderivative

Tags: integration

The [wikipedia article on antiderivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Antiderivatives_of_non-continuous_functions) states:

> Non-continuous functions can have antiderivatives. [...]
>
> - In some cases, the antiderivatives of such pathological functions may be found by Riemann integration, while in other cases these
>     functions are not Riemann integrable.

I'm looking for an example of such a function - a bounded function $f : [a, b] \to [m, M]$ that has an antiderivative $F$ such that $F' = f$ on its domain, while $f$ is not Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Regarding a possible duplicate: [integrability equivalent to having antiderivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239324/is-integrability-equivalent-to-having-antiderivative)

Answers provided there (in the first 3 answers at least) provide a function that is integrable, but doesn't have an antiderivative. I'm looking for the opposite example here (has an antiderivative, but not R-integrable). However, one of the links from that questions points to an example of such a function that is not L-integrable (although I'm still interested in the R-integration).

Comment: Look at this function [Volterra function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Now that your function is bounded, by Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, your function must not be continuous a.e. Now this link gives you the whole gamut of differentiable functions that have derivatives that are discontinuous on sets of different measures/sizes. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/231021

You want the one in the last part "Increasing the measure". That will guarantee that your function is discontinuous on a set of Lebesgue measure greater than $0$. Now you have to ensure that it is bounded and the example in the comments is one of those.

Here's another link, where they talk about construction of such functions with bounded derivatives everywhere on$[0,1]$ but such that the derivatives are discontinuous on a set of positive measure. (see 5.5.5.d):

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1WY6u0C_jEsC&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=derivative+discontinuous+measure+bounded&source=bl&ots=JtO97c8t60&sig=5YGv2dnZpJ-OO5Uzdodt7BRwnuk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XvY2VYy5A4fpaKClgbAO&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=derivative%20discontinuous%20measure%20bounded&f=false

Old post before the bounded restriction: Try unbounded functions. They cannot have Riemann integrals, yet some are continuous on an open interval. What about $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$ does not exist (Riemann integrable functions are by definition bounded, and this function is not, on $(0,1)$) but it has an antiderivative $\ln(x)$ everywhere on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Well, Riemann integration is initially defined only on a compact interval (and only for bounded functions).. so I would prefer an example within those boundaries. Also, the wiki article's usage of the word "pathological" leads me to believe such an example exists.

Comment: @edited with a new link, and the one in the comments, the Volterra function, works too. It's a concrete example