# What is the difference between antiderivative and derivative?

Tags: calculus

I am in calculus class right now and I have no idea. I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Don't feel sorry about your ignorance, just be confident and learn. It is not a big deal to not knowing something, you can always learn. Remember things takes time. All the best.

Comment: Antiderivative is going in the opposite direction.  Since the derivative of $3x^3-4$ is $9x^2$, we conclude that an antiderivative of $9x^2$ is $3x^3-4$.  I said "an" antiderivative, because there are many of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative can be defined as the slope of a tangent line. When taking a derivative the general formula to follow would be:

1. Constant Rule $\frac{d(c)}{dx}=0$

The antiderivative, also referred to as an integral, can be thought of as the inverse operation for the derivative. In other words, it is the opposite of a derivative.

It is important to recognize that there are specific derivative/ antiderivative  rules that need to be applied to particular problems

Example: The antiderivative of $\sec^2x = \tan x + C$

It is also important to remember, when taking the antiderivative, not to forget to add your constant!

Answer (score 0):

Anti derivative is integration indefinite integration gives any equation relating $x,y$ while definite  integration  is  area under the given curve while derivatives is finding the slope of given curve . Thats what the basic difference and definitions are. But i would also like to tell you never forget to write $+c$(constant) when you have found out the integration result as its very important. You will get it as you proceed further in calculus

Comment: Anti-differentiation produces the function that describes the area under the curve. Definite integration is used to compute the area.

Answer (score 0):

The anti-derivative of a function, denoted by
$$\int f(x)dx$$
yields a function that when differentiated, gives back $f(x)$, while differentiating denoted by
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$
yields a function for the slope of the tangent line at any given $x$ which youre probably used to by now.

Answer (score 0):

There is not only a difference between antiderivative but also a relation ship. Antiderivative is a "sort of inversve of the derivative" (note, this is not really true, just a somewhat intuitive description, which is the reason for quotations) in the sense of if $f=F'$ then $f$ is derivative of $F$ and $F$ is antiderivative of $f$. Antiderivative is often denoted as an integral, i.e. $F=\int f$ but there is examples of $\int f(x)dx = L$ where no $F(x)$ exists, for example see this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239324/is-integrability-equivalent-to-having-antiderivative).

Answer (score 0):

Derivative is rate of change and it can also find the slope as well, in it you can find the piece wise change, while anti-derivative  is synonimus to intergration which is inverse of derivatives, it is sometimes used to find the area under the curve, also to find the length of the curve $y=f(x)$