# Function that has no antiderivative

Tags: integration

Can someone give an example of a function $f:$ $]-1,1[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that has no antiderivative? Is there a certain "class" of functions which share this characteristic? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does that notation mean? is (-1,1) the domain or range

Comment: That's the domain.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239324/120540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}$As the previous answer suggests, the good example is the signum function. If $F'(x)=\sgn(x)$ for any $x$, then $F'(x)=1$ if $x>0$, so then $F(x)=x+C$. Similarly for $x<0$ we have $F(x)=-x+D$. Of course, $F$ should be continuous at $0$. Because $F(0+)=C$ and $F(0-)=D$, we get $F(0)=C=D$. Hence $F(x)=|x|+C$ for any $x$. But $F$ is not differentiable and it could not be an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Any function that does not have the intermediate value property does not have an antiderivative.

This can be seen as an immediate consequence of Darboux theorem, but I am sure there are more "fundamental" ways to prove it

Comment: Isn't this claim just a paraphasing of Darboux's theotrem itself? If it had a more elementary proof, then that proof would also prove Darboux itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point.