# Compute the coefficients of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=\frac{x^2-x}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof, solution-verification

Compute the coefficients of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=\frac{x^2-x}{4}.$

If I already computed the coefficient for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=x^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=x,$ can I just divide both series by 4 and then subtract them and the sum would be the coefficient $A_n$ of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=\frac{x^2-x}{4}$ ,

Am I right?

If I am not right, then is there an easier way to compute the coefficient other than compute the complicated integral ?

Comment: You are right (because the integral is linear). See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}$ are
$A_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l f(x)\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}\; dx$.

The coefficients of $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}$ are
$B_n=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l g(x)\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}\; dx$.

Thus, the coefficients of $\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}$ are
\begin{align*}C_n&=\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l (\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x))\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}\; dx\\
&=\alpha\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l f(x)\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}\; dx+\beta\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l g(x)\sin \tfrac{n \pi x}{l}\; dx\\
&=\alpha A_n+\beta B_n\end{align*}

Taking $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=x$, $\alpha=\tfrac{1}{4}$ and $\beta=-\tfrac{1}{4}$ we conclude that

- the coefficients of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\sin\tfrac{n\pi x}{l}=\frac{x^2-x}{4}$ are $C_n=\frac{A_n-B_n}{4}$

where

- $A_n$ are the coefficients of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=x^2$
- $B_n$ are the coefficients of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}=x$.

So, yes. You can.

Comment: ah ok, at first I thought it was a crazy idea, but it wasn't, thanks!

Comment: Will the integral be always linear (independently of the problem)?

Comment: @Isa You are welcome. Actually, this kind of idea (i.e. reduce a problem to a form which has already been solved) is very common in mathematics (by the way, it is a source of jokes like [this](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~ewkiss/jokes.html#1) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2143)). With respect to the question, yes (in the sense that the second formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Linearity) holds provided that $f,g$ are integrable and $\alpha,\beta$ are constants). See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370998/show-that-integration-is-a-linear-operator).